Powershell, Get-WinEvent -Computername xxx, deferred output evaluation?
I try to get events on a remote domain controller and it takes several minutes even for the simplest request (the same request executed locally on the DC is very fast)
$events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ logname='security';starttime='2024/09/19 12:00';endtime='2024/09/19 12:01'} -Computername DC1
$events.count 
# output: 233

if now I want to see the events
$events 
# first time, takes as long as the Get-WinEvent command

but the second time, its instantaneous.
if during first time I stop the display with ctrl-C and ask again to show $events content, the first records, those that have already been displayed, appear instantaneously but the rest of then take ages to show.
it looks like the resulting array only contains just stubs of EvenLogRecord that are lazily evaluated on demand by querying again the remote computer and replaced by the real value once evaluated.
I tried to google for that stub thing but found nothing. do you have any clue?

if you CTRL+C during the 2nd statement you simply will have the output from the previous assignment. Thats powershell default behavior. Example: $a = 0..10; $a = 10..0 | % { sleep 1; $_ <# ctrl+c here #> }

The Message property value on each event log record is lazily rendered from message templates on access. Consider calling Get-WinEvent on the remote machine with Invoke-Command, and then pipe to Select-Object in that remote session, so that you only receive already-rendered string values locally (or objects where the message property has already been discarded)

@MathiasR.Jessen do you have any resource in which I can learn more on that topic ?
